# How to compare an instance of string with a parameterised format string in .net

Tags: .net, string, string-formatting

Is there way in .NET to check that a particular instance of a string matches a given format string? So say my format string is "Hello, {0}!" and I have "Hello, World!", to use an old cliched example, I'm looking for a comparison method that will return true when comparing these. I know I could write a String extension method for doing this but just want to make sure I'm not about to reinvent the wheel...

If anyone's interested, the reason I'm asking is because I'm writing an NUnit test to verify a message being displayed to the user but I don't know or care what the code inserts into the params for the format string, I just want to check that it uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the easiest would be to use regular expressions, as in:

```
var template = "Hello, {0}!";
var test = "Hello, World!";

var pattern = Regex.Replace("^"+Regex.Escape(template)+"$", "\\\\{[0-9]+\\}", ".*?");
var matches = Regex.IsMatch(test, pattern); // true if test matches template
```

The idea here is that you want to "transform" template into a regular expression by substituting the pattern `.*?` for each occurrence of `{n}` and also enclosing the result within `^` and `$` so that it only matches as a whole.

But in order to do that, you need to `Regex.Escape` `template` first because in the general case it may contain characters that have special meaning in regular expressions. Escaping leaves patterns like `{n}` looking like `\{n}`, so that's what we target using the expression `\\\\{[0-9]+\\}` in the "replace {n} with .*?" part.

Comment: Yes, nice solution - that's something like what I had in mind if I need to write a string extension method. I'm looking for an inbuilt way of doing it though... I thought there might be one but I'm just having trouble finding it.

Comment: @Cat: There is no built-in way to do this, because with the information we have the problem is not solvable unless you make assumptions about what the user wants (which is what I did when deciding that the replace pattern would be `.*?`), and even then this method can return wrong results if you engineer the inputs (e.g. `test = "Hello, World!x!"` will not match and never will be able to).

Comment: Ok, I will probably go with writing the extension method and using your code then. Thank you. I'm so used to using String.Format("put something here {0}", "here you go") that I assumed there must be in an inbuilt way of then checking to see if the output of that matches the format string...

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, "^Hello, .*!$")
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that my format strings are in resource files and I don't want to have to hard code a regular expression for every message I have. I tried the above with var match = Regex.Match(input, UserPrompts.HelloSomeone) and the match came back as false.